# Dynamically import data from one work book to another with progressive pages

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have two excel workbooks. 1st workbook has all the information I need that are sorted by machines and 3 number inputs following the machines, the inputs for this workbook is created in this format;

Machine 1 | Number 1 | Number 2 | Number 3 |
Machine 2 | Number 1 | Number 2 | Number 3 |
Machine 3 | Number 1 | Number 2 | Number 3 |

The workbook is separated by Sheets that has a new one created each day to input the numbers for the day.

2nd workbook has each of the machines separated per sheet with the inputs being the numbers taken from the 1st workbook per day on each row.

How can I (If possible at all) dynamically have the numbers import to the 2nd worksheet that is updated with the current days numbers on the 1st workbook?

I have tried a couple of conditional formats that ended up not being successful, and attempting to link the cell from one work book to another. Nothing worked successfully.

Comment: If you use excel formula all formulas will be recalculated when you modify something on a sheet. This is not the efficient approach. With VBA code you can provide the solution only for the specific date you need.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple sheets, and there will be a different number of sheets every day, Power Query would be better.

In your 2nd workbook, create a new query to get the data from your first workbook. Combine all the sheets. Then unpivot the numbers. That will give you a table with all days, machines, and numbers.

Here is the code from some sample data, but you would need to learn a bit about Power Query to figure out which column names etc. to change because your data will be different.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\your.name\Documents\your_file.xlsx"), null, true),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Item", "Kind", "Hidden"}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", Table.ColumnNames(Table.Combine(#"Removed Columns"[Data]))),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Data",{{"Column1", "Machine"}, {"Column2", "Number1"}, {"Column3", "Number2"}, {"Column4", "Number3"}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Renamed Columns", {"Name", "Machine"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Columns"
```

Then on each of your machine sheets, you can use `SUMIFS` to get the number you need, or just create a pivot table from the data.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]